# Merge two multidimensional array in vuejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two arrays. What I'm trying to do is to merge them together and overwrites the value of the index. This is the arrays I have:

```
var array1 = [
    ["","","","","","",""],
    ["","","","","","",""],
    ["","","","","","",""],
];

var array2 = [
    ["a","",""],
    ["","b",""]
];
```

my expected output is

```
var output = [
    ["a","","","","","",""],
    ["","b","","","","",""],
    ["","","","","","",""]
];
```

But the result I get is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axtgt.png)

What I tried so far is `array1.concat(array2)`. I really don't want to use long foreach as possible so I can prevent a long codes. Can anyone give me suggestions on how to achieve the output I wanted? Thank you.

Comment: do you want 2 dimensional array in result?

Comment: @NileshPatel my expected output is the two array will merge.

Comment: result will be having single dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work, though it assumes `array2` has preference over `array1` and never has more rows than `array1`.

```js
const array1 = [
    ["","","","","","",""],
    ["","","","","","",""],
    ["","","","","","",""],
];

const array2 = [
    ["a","",""],
    ["","b",""]
];

const output = array2
    // pad array2's values with extra values from array1
    .map((row, idx) => row.concat(array1[idx].slice(row.length)))
    // add any missing rows
    .concat(array1.slice(array2.length));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
const res = array1.map((row, i) => {
    if(i < array2.length) {
       updatedRow = [...array2[i], ...row];
       updatedRow.splice(array2[i].length -1 , array2[i].length);
       return updatedRow;
   }
   return row;
});
console.log(res);
```